# Latex font error ... I can't find 'hv'

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive

I want to compile my PNAS journal document. I am unable to do so. Since I am new to this latex community I am not much aware of the packages that need to be installed.

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm hv
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map typeface abbreviation v for hv.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/skak/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input hv
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf hv
! I can't find file `hv'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input hv

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input hv

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: hv.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input hv' failed to make hv.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font \footnotefont=hv at 6.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
l.165 \font\footnotefont\frutigermed at 6pt

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436 to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

This PNAS style file (from http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml) has a rather old fashioned view of fonts.  The problem is the file `PNASTWOF.STY`.  In the sample file this is listed as an optional package, so the simplest thing to do is just comment out that line in the sample, i.e. add `%` in front of that line so you get

```
...
%% ADDITIONAL OPTIONAL STYLE FILES
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pnastwoF}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
...
```

The file will then compile using standard LaTeX fonts.

If instead you want to try to complie the sample as is, then look in the file `PNASTWOF.STY`.  There you will see a comment

> ```
> %% You may need to rename these fonts to match the
> %% names of the .tfm files on your system.
> ```

It is not quite as bad as that though.  Essentially there are two sections where `Dvipsone Names` should be commented and `Karl Berry Names` uncommented:

Firstly change the commenting (`%` characters) in the Times Roman section to

```
%% Times-Roman

%% Dvipsone Names:
%\def\timesroman{tir}
%\def\timesbold{tib}
%\def\timesitalic{tii}
%\def\timesbolditalic{tibi}


%% Karl Berry Names:
\def\timesroman{ptmr8t}
\def\timesbold{ptmb8t}
\def\timesitalic{ptmri8t}
\def\timesbolditalic{ptmbi8t}
```

Next change the commenting in the Helevtica section to

```
%% Helvetica
%------------------
%% Dvipsone
%\def\helvetica{hv}
%\def\helveticaoblique{hvo}
%\def\helveticaboldoblique{hvbo}
%\def\helveticabold{hvb}


%% Karl Berry Names:
\def\helvetica{phvr}
\def\helveticaoblique{phvro}
\def\helveticaboldoblique{phvbo}
\def\helveticabold{phvb}
```

This was sufficient for me to compile the sample document from the site.