# Latex font error - does not print helveticaboldoblique

Tags: fonts

After I compile my PNAS journal document, a part of the references should be in helvetica-boldoblique style. However, it is printed simple bold (helvetica-bold). When I change the font settings in the style and class file from boldoblique to oblique, it text will be italic but not bold anymore.

I have tried this solution, but it is not working: [Latex font error ... I can't find 'hv'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126311/latex-font-error-i-cant-find-hv)

Files available at: http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml

Comment: This is a very late welcome, but welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It's unlike us to miss a first post like this. Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How do you load the fonts?

Answer (score 2):

Without a MWE it's extremely hard to tell, but this is classic (and expected) behavior when you use the deprecated styling commands `\bf` and `\it`.

LaTeX uses two classes of commands for the job.

- One class behaves similar to `\bf` and `\it`, but they are called `\bfseries` and `\itshape`.
  These should be enclosed in braces to limit the scope of their effect:

  ```
  {\bfseries Bold   text}
  {\itshape  Italic text}
  {\bfseries\itshape Bold {\em and} italic text!}
  ```
- The other class takes arguments for the scope, and can perform some intelligent corrections to typography as a result.

  ```
  \textbf{Bold   text}
  \textit{Italic text}
  \textbf{\textit{Bold \emph{and} italic text!}
  ```

See ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text) for an in-depth discussion of these commands and the differences between them.