# Molecular Biology and Evolution template - help fix bit rotted font definitions (and other things)

Tags: fonts, errors, installing

I am trying to get the [Molecular Biology and Evolution journal article](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/molbev/for_authors/mbe_latex_nov2013.zip) template to build. I have limited experience with LaTeX except as a consumer of existing packages.

The linked zip file contains two sub zips, the one I have been attempting to get to compile is "MBE_LaTeX.zip" (the other lacks necessary class files etc.).

Freshly extracted, `latex MBE-Sample.tex` results in a failure so:

```
<snip>

kpathsea: Running mktextfm CRONOS
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation C for CRONOS.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/skak/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input CRONOS
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf CRONOS
! I can't find file `CRONOS'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input CRONOS

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input CRONOS

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: CRONOS.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input CRONOS' failed to make CRONOS.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font LY1/ptm/m/n/10=CRONOS at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

?     
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

No pages of output.
Transcript written on MBE-Sample.log.
```

This appears to be related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126311/latex-font-error-i-cant-find-hv), but I am unable to figure out the correct name/installation for the CRONOS font (it is provided in the Fonts directory in the zip file).

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, it would be helpful to leave a comment suggesting how it might be improved.

Comment: MBE.cls is absolutely hopeless. The sample file, the class and the support packages seem to be written with the assumption that the Y&Y TeX system is installed. The supplied fonts seem to lack all the tfm files needed to make them work with TeX (that's where our errors come from). I would suggest you contact the journal editors to ask what kind of PDF they will accept, and then try to achieve that with standard LaTeX classes and packages.

Comment: Yes, from my reading of the code, that was my view of it too. I have contacted the journal and hope to get some help from there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: I had similar troubles with the 2014 template. It turns out that sometimes fonts are referred to in CAPITAL LETTERS which produces exactly the error mentioned above. If those font names are changed to lower letters, compilation worked (e.g., `CMR10` to `cmr10`).

Comment: FYI, I downloaded the package from MBE today and still ran into this issue.  This post was very useful to find.